# JavaFX - Limit TextArea rows?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, limit, maxlength

In Swing I created a custom Document which was able to determine and limit the number of rows in a TextArea whether a line was being wrapped or a line feed was pressed.  I was hoping to find something similar in FX, but haven't been able to.  Any suggestions for how to handle limiting the number of rows allowed?

Edit: This is how I was attempting to figure out how many wrapped lines are in the TextArea.  The biggest issue is getting the exact width to pass into the setWrappingWidth because there seems to be some padding on the TextArea's content along with borders.

```
Text helper = new Text();
helper.setText(text);
helper.setFont(getFont());
helper.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(widthBinding);
Font font = getFont();
FontMetrics fontMetrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(font);
int preferredHeight = new Double(helper.getLayoutBounds().getHeight()).intValue();
int lineHeight = new Double(fontMetrics.getMaxAscent() + fontMetrics.getMaxDescent()).intValue();
System.err.println("preferredHeight / lineHeight: " + preferredHeight / lineHeight);
return preferredHeight / lineHeight;
```

Comment: doesn't `.setPrefRowCount(10);` work? with wrapText set to true? also textarea respects its area so it tries hard to fill it up, unless you limit it with maxsize or something

Comment: As far as I know setPrefRowCount and setPrefColCount only factor into the preferred sizing of the TextArea and not limiting the content.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. You can't expect the lines to be limited while you e. g. make the textarea smaller. It's a usability nightmare. What's the use case for this?

Comment: The size isn't changing.  Say a TextArea is defined with 10 rows and 40 columns.  The preferred size is set and doesn't change, but in certain circumstances I will want to limit the text to 400 characters and/or 10 lines.  The Text node was being used as a helper to determine the current preferred size in order to figure out how many wrapped lines are currently in the field (since line feeds are not present if a line wraps). Sorry for any confusion I've been away from my computer and trying to keep up on my phone.

Comment: So if you have 400 characters, the first 10 characters being line feeds, you only want to have the 10 line feeds in case the textarea is shrinked to a 1 character column width? Still doesn't make any sense to limit by number of lines instead of limiting by number of characters.

Comment: We are rewriting our GUI from Swing to FX which has been a big process.  The goal was to not have to also change any of our Server side code.  We previously had a number of TextAreas in Swing that were say 3 lines of 40 or 5 lines of 40 that did not allow text wrapping (so a line feed was required to get to the new line).  The Server code would then split the text on the line feeds to enter into the 3x40 or 5x40 database fields.  When wrapping is turned on, it makes it more difficult to determine how many lines exist in the field and limit the input.  Also, the width/height is never shrinking.

Answer (score 8):

Every `TextInputControl` got a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textFormatterProperty) for this task since Java 8 Update 40.

It has two functionalities of which this one can be used for your Task:

> A filter (getFilter()) that can intercept and modify user input. This helps to keep the text in the desired format.

This is a very primitive attempt to solve this:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setTextFormatter(createTextFormatter());
        root.setCenter(textArea);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <T> TextFormatter<T> createTextFormatter() {

        final IntegerProperty lines = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

        return new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
            if (change.isAdded()) {
                if (change.getText().indexOf('\n') > -1) {
                    lines.set(lines.get() + 1);
                }
                if (lines.get() > 10) {
                    change.setText("");
                }
            }
            return change;
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This successfully prevents the user from entering more than 10 lines. But you should improve this solution, for example to handle:

- text was replaced
- text was deleted

The `TextFormatter` is really powerful and should be able to handle all this.

Comment: I will look into this in a few hours.  I believe the hard(er) part is calculating the number of lines due to the text wrapping in the field as opposed to the user pressing the enter key.  I am not near my PC at the moment, but I was close to solving this issue by using a Text node.

Comment: @Tommo But now you changed the scope of your question entirely.. from "How (which methods, class files) can I limit the number of lines in a TextField" to "How to determine the number of lines in a TextField"..

Comment: Well they kind of go hand in hand don't they?  Determining the number of lines is almost a requirement in being able to limit the number of lines.

Comment: Well that depends on several things. So not necessarily, no. E.g. We went from "number of lines" (this usually means strings seperated by the new line character(s)) to number of wrapped lines..

Comment: The first line of the question did say whether the line was being wrapped or line feed was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Assigned the TextFormatter via:

```
setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
  if(change.isContentChange()) {
    if(getWrappedLines(change.getControlText(), change.getControlNewText()) > maxRows) {
      change.setText("");
    }
  }
  return change;
}));
```

And the getWrappedLines method:

```
int getWrappedLines(String oldText, String newText) {
  Text helper = (Text)lookup(".text");
  if(helper != null) {
    helper.setText(newText);
    FontMetrics fontMetrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(getFont());
    int preferredHeight = new Double(helper.getLayoutBounds().getHeight()).intValue();
    int lineHeight = new Double(fontMetrics.getLineHeight()).intValue();
    // Initially a line's preferredHeight = 14, however each new line seems   to increase the preferredHeight by
    // 16 instead of 14.
    preferredHeight = preferredHeight == lineHeight ? preferredHeight : preferredHeight - 2;
    helper.setText(oldText);
    return preferredHeight / lineHeight;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
```

}

Comment: just copy/pasted together from this page, no research, not your solution.

Comment: Suggesting a TextFormatter was a step in the right direction, however the getWrappedLines method was something I posted originally.  Combining the two solved the problem.

Comment: I completely agree.  I just figured I would post what seems to work for me  in case anyone else came along and had a similar problem, or a better suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (not optimized, only use if the text is not too long):

```
  int maxRowCount = 3;
  new TextArea().setTextFormatter (new TextFormatter<> (change -> {
    if (change.isContentChange ()) {
      if (change.getControlNewText ().chars ().filter (a -> a == '\n').count () > maxRowCount - 1) {
        change.setText ("");
      }
    }
    return change;
  }));
```